# Superposition of two waves

Tags: waves, superposition

How can I simplify the superposition of two waves, $\vec{E}_1 = A\sin(kz-\omega t)\hat{x}$ and $\vec{E}_2 = A\sin(-kz-\omega t)\hat{y}$ where $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are unit vectors? This is in the context of quantum mechanics

Comment: Hello @cromulentacorn and welcome to Physics SE. It could prove to be beneficial to provide some more information on your problem to allow people to help you. You could provide some "intuition" on what exactly simplification means to you and whether you have tried anything that you didn't manage to solve your problem. You could also "guide" people towards a desired type of solution if you already have an idea on what a possible solution could look like (roughly).

Answer (score 1):

$\hat{x}$ and $\hat y$ are linearly independent vectors. The sum of two vectors is the sum of their components *in order*. So $$\vec E_1 + \vec E_2 = A\sin(kz-\omega t)\hat x - A\sin(kz+\omega t)\hat y$$.